# How to inspect the SQL generated by Django for a multi-tenant application to ensure the tenant is filtered?

Tags: django, postgresql

I have a multi-tenant Django application with a single database. Where data belongs to a single tenant, the table has a tenant_id column.

At the moment we are manually adding the tenant filter through manager methods for each model, but it is easy to forget adding the filter.

For the relevant tables, is there some way that I can inspect the SQL to ensure that it contains the tenant filter when using the Django ORM?

I want to add this as an extra precaution to ensure that no data leaks between tenants.

Is this possible?

We're using a postgres DB

Comment: Have you tried to use RLS for the separation of tenants?

Comment: @EugeneK First time I've heard about it - will take a look thanks

Comment: I'm curious - no value judgement. Why did you not use the built-in sites framework?

Comment: @Melvyn I don't see how the sites framework would have solved this?

Comment: It wouldn't. The problem would be identical. I'm curious what made you decide against the sites framework and roll your own? Just as personal interest. Over the years, number 1 reason I've heard is "didn't know it existed" followed by "our tenant model isn't tied t hostname".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible solution can be using [RLS](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/ddl-rowsecurity.html).
To make it work you need to activate RLS on each table you want to protect and then create RLS policy that will use session variable (set per user). To populate the session variable with a user-specific filter you create a Middleware.

1. Enable RLS on the table

```sql
    alter table {table_name} enable row level security;
```

2. Force table's owner to obey RLS as well

```sql
    alter table {table_name} force row level security;
```

3. Create a policy that restricts access to specific operations using a session variable.

```sql
    create policy {policy_name} on {table_name}
    for SELECT using (
        tenant_id = current_setting('rls.tenant_id', 't') or
        current_setting('rls.tenant_id', 't') is null
    );
```

4. Create Middleware that will populate the session variable

```py
    from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin
    from django.db import connection
    
    
    class RLSMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):
        def process_view(self, request, **kwargs):
            with connection.cursor() as cur:
                cur.execute("""select set_config('rls.tenant_id', %(value)s, false)""", dict(value=request.user.pk))
```

5. To automate creation of such rules you can customize database backend with custom schema editor.
   `db/backends/postgresql/base.py`

```py
from django.db.backends.postgresql.schema import DatabaseSchemaEditor
from django.db.backends.postgresql.base import DatabaseWrapper as BaseDatabaseWrapper


class SchemaEditor(DatabaseSchemaEditor):
    def create_model(self, model):
        super().create_model(model)
        if self._is_multitenant_model(model):
            self.create_rls_policy(model)

    def _is_multitenant_model(self, model):
        # any custom logic to detect multi-tenant model
        for for field in model._meta.local_fields:
            if field.name == 'tenant_id':
                return True
        return False

    def create_rls_policy(self, model):
        table_name = self.quote_name(model._meta.db_table)
        policy_name = self.quote_name('policy')
        self.execute('alter table {table_name} enable row level security'.format(table_name=table_name))
        self.execute('alter table {table_name} force row levelsecurity'.format(table_name=table_name))
        self.execute("""
            create policy {policy_name} on {table_name}
            for SELECT using (
                tenant_id = current_setting('rls.tenant_id', 't') or
                current_setting('rls.tenant_id', 't') is null)
        """.format(policy_name=policy_name, table_name=table_name)


class DatabaseWrapper(BaseDatabaseWrapper):
    """Wraps the standard PostgreSQL database backend.
    """
    SchemaEditorClass = SchemaEditor
```

in database connection just specify your backend like this:

```py
DATABASES = {
...
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'db.backends.postgresql',
...

}
```

Comment: Aren't you just shifting the problem from "forgetting to add manager filter" to "forgetting to activate RLS on the new table for the new model"?

Comment: @Melvyn yes, on the high level it looks like memorizing problem is still here, but the creation of rules can be automated with custom `DatabaseSchemaEditor` that inspect table columns. The approach with the manager, on the other hand, will not guarantee access to the table using correct manager.

Comment: I like this approache, so hence the bounty for a complete answer.

Comment: @Melvyn I have updated my answer with some basic example, I haven't run it though

Comment: Awesome. Looks good enough to get started for OP. As a code review: wrap arguments in `self.quote_*()`. WIll award bounty when I can and thanks for shedding some light on corners that sadly don't come up often anymore.

Comment: @Melvyn thanks, I have updated arguments, there are others things needs to be fixed before this can be used as-is, but I agree good enough to describe the idea.

Comment: @EugeneK Wow, I think this is the most detailed answer I've ever seen on SO! Thanks so much! This is exactly what I was looking for.